# How to override MVC2 model value for model property for Textbox.Text value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got a model with a `DateOfBirth` property on it, and in the view that uses that model, I've got a textbox:

```
Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth")
```

I'm using DataAnnotations on the model, and validation works properly, and the textbox's value is loaded from the model. However, I don't want that value to be what is initially displayed, but rather its `ToShortDate()` value. But I can't seem to override the model's value. Even if I put "ASDF" as the value parameter of the `TextBox` method, the model's value is what ends up in the text box. I've also tried using a `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d")]` attribute, but that didn't help, either.

So how can I override the model's value with its `ToShortDate()` value?

Comment: I can work around the problem by using straight HTML, not just an HTML helper, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to get the HTML helper to accept a value, or at least a format string data annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's not a good way around this. Perhaps specifying an HTML attribute to override, but the inline HTML is good enough for now. I'd welcome an alternative, though.